# Validate fields only with Required attribute also with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using the required attribute on inputs all around my website to front-end validate form submissions. I'm also doing validation on the back-end.

It seems that Safari and IE does not fully support the "required" attribute..

So I was thinking of writing a quick, universal jQuery function to do some validation when the browser does not support it, somethink like this:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){

    $(this).children().each(function(){

        if ($(this).prop('required') && $(this).val() === ""){
            alert('field has no value');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

I just typed the example code, so there might be some errors.

Also, is it really recommended that I also do some javascript/jquery validation on the front-end fields? Or maybe just the 'required' attribute will take care of it.

Comment: Doesn't the jquery validator also support adding `required` as a class name?

Comment: I'm not really sure you're asking a question? Can you elaborate? Is your code not working? If so what's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5, a required tag will validate the fields within the browser without the requirement of any Javascript, jQuery or PHP code.

You can find the list of ways it validates dependant on the type here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

When it comes to a fallback, using some sort of jQuery functionality would be good but should only be called on the browsers that require it, otherwise you can cause conflicts with the browsers that do allow for it.

Using HTML if tags to determine if to include the file would be best.

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
```

To accomplish the validation, you'll need to do a checkup on the form submission, prevent the default functionality and then do a find against the elements that you need.

Something along these lines:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(':input[required]:visible').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('span.form_error').text('A required field was not filled out');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="small_text" required />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <span class="form_error"></span>
</form>
```

Hope this all makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this attribute [isn't fully supported across all browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp), and you have said that you are happy to use JQuery for your validation, I would suggest using the [jquery validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), which will validate your form based on either the attributes or class names of your input fields.

```
<form>
<label for='name'>Name</label>  
<input id='name' class='required'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').validate();
})
</script>
```

```js
    
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('form').validate();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form>
    <label for='name'>Name</label>  
    <input id='name' class='required'>
    <input type='submit' value='validate'>
</form>
```